# Ubuntu 20.04 MODEM 4G LTE how read SMS messages?

Tags: modem

Thanks for reading my question.
Ubuntu 20.04.6 and using an generic chinese MODEM 4G LTE.
Hardinfo report as being Qualcomm Android.
Modem Manager GUI not have access to that modem. Possibly the modem works as being an network adapter.
Configuration is accessed using 192.168.100.1 in browser, but not any information about SMS.

Is possible read and send SMS messages in MODEM 4G LTE ? If yes what is the software ?

Thanks for your reply.